# Macbook Pro 2018 - Battery drain since update while shut down

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

My Macbook Pro is starting to have power management issues. I tried alrady NVRAM / PRAM Reset and SMC Reset to no avail.

I regularly shut down my Macbook over the night. Since a few weeks, the battery is always drained to 0% when i boot it up the next morning. I noticed, that even if the Macbook is off for several hours, it still is warm, as if there is something working even though the notebook is completely turned off. I have PowerNap deactivated.

This all started occuring since the 11.3 or 11.2 update.

The only thing i have not tried, reinstalling, which i would like to avoid because of time constraints. Battery health is "normal" according to OSX.

Comment: How many battery Charge Cycles? (You can find this in System Information > Power.)

Comment: 84 cycles charged

Comment: That's surprisingly low for a 3-year-old laptop. Has it been mostly plugged in?

Comment: Yeah it was mostly plugged in. Strangely also, that if i do not plug it in, it works just fine. No stronger battery drain than usual. It's just battery drain when the notebook is shut down and turned off, and it started appearing after an update and also doesn't also happen always. (usually it works for a day after other updates).

Comment: Are you saying that the battery drains when it's shutdown AND it's plugged in? That makes no sense. Something's faulty: maybe the charger cable, or the battery itself.

Comment: No, i apologize for the confusion. I unplug it usually when it is shut down. When i use it on battery, the battery doesn't drain faster than it always did.

Answer (score 0):

If your battery is losing charge even when you've shutdown the laptop, then I'd agree that there is something wrong with it, and you should take it to an Apple Store or other authorised shop.

It's impossible for it to be a software issue if it's happening when no software is running (i.e. OFF).